# Store calculated field value in other field

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to store the value of a calculated field in another field (preferably by the click of a link/button next to the calculated field). On each click of this button the value of the calculated field should be inserted in the field below the previous stored insertion.
I hope this makes sense :-)

**Example**

In A1 is a formula that calculates values based on variables. On every change of the variables I want to be able to save the result in A1 by the click of a button (eg. button in B1). The first time I click the button, the result should be saved in C1. The next time I click the button, the new result should be saved in C2 (and C1 shall remain unchanged). Third time in C3 and so forth.
The storing of the values should at least remain stored in the current "session" of the workbook (meaning until I close the workbook).

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you haven't tried anything at all. This is not too complex, with a bit of research and after doing some tests you should be able to come up with it without any problem.

Comment: Sorry! That might be true. I tried to look it up but I don't know VBA pretty much at all. It's great to find help here. Thanks!

Comment: Next time, perhaps you should do some pre-research and work by your own (usually, coming here without any code is not welcome). In any case, you have got your help from JDunkerley and thus should show your appreciation by awarding its answer as the right one. Why don't try to do what you have requested him by your own? You have a pretty solid first step to work with (his code).

Comment: This is btw my first question ever on StackOverflow, so sorry if I do not know all the routines yet.

Comment: No problem. The ideas are very easy: this is not a free code-delivering service; this is meant for programmers who want to grow and who face problems they cannot solve or are looking for the best alternative by asking more experienced ones. Thus, you should always have worked by your own on the problem before asking here (that is, asking when there is no other option; not by default). Bear in mind that your question/the answer is meant to be helfpul to others (better don't focus on your specific problems, but on general ones). Lastly, it is always nice when your help is appraised/rewarded :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    ' Get Value Cell (In first sheet cell A1)
    Dim rA1 As Range
    Set rA1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

    ' Get Top Cell In History (In first sheet cell C1)
    Dim rC1 As Range
    Set rC1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C1")

    ' Is The Top Cell Empty, If Not Find First Empty Cell In Column
    If (rC1.Value <> "") Then
        ' If cell below C1 has a value then go to end of line of number
        If (rC1.Offset(1).Value <> "") Then
            Set rC1 = rC1.End(xlDown)
        End If

        ' Offset 1 cell to get empty cell
        Set rC1 = rC1.Offset(1)
    End If

    ' Set Value of first blank to value cell
    rC1.Value = rA1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: That works great! Can you add a tiny feature? How to stop the formula from inserting values into more fields if there are no more empty fields below. E.g predefining a max number of 5 or any other number.  And maybe a couple of comments in the code? :-)

Comment: Added some comments of what it doing. If you want it to only go a certain range then that would involve adjust the block that finds the bottom

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks alot. I'll try to find some tutorials to understand more of VBA and be able to make the correction, that I need.